# Is It Possible to Reroute I2C Path from One Device to Another if End Device is Same?

Tags: i2c, multiplexer

I have a master and slave device that has two MUXs inbetween. Let's call these MUXs MUX1 and MUX2, and layout goes MASTER --> MUX1--> MUX2 --> SLAVE DEVICE. My design also has a separate MUX called MUX3 that's also connected to MUX1 and SLAVE device that's currently not in use. Would it be possible in SW to reroute my current I2C to go from MASTER --> MUX1 --> MUX3 --> SLAVE DEVICE?

Comment: I don't see why not as along as it is an I2C-controlled double-pole analog mux. You run the I2C to the mux's I2C lines and its mux lines. Kind of clunky though.

Comment: It seems that in general there should be no problems. But the details are missing so feel free to provide them (schematics and chips used etc)

Comment: If these are proper I2C muxed I don't see a problem. Schematic would be useful.